# How to write .property() with coffee script in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

The coffee compilation always fails when I want to write a .property() of my controller's property with coffee script:

```
App.TestController = Em.Controller.extend
    fullName: ->
        (@get 'name') + 123
    .property 'name'
```

When I compile the code above, the console always reported the error that sth wrong with the .property('name')
In Javascript, I will write like this:

```
App.TestController = Em.Controller.extend({
    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('name') + 123;
    }.property('name')
});
```

Any idea to write this in coffee script? Thanks

Comment: Please pay attention to the *Similar Questions* list that shows up in the sidebar when you're asking a question, the duplicate was at the top of the list.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way that I've found thus far is:

```
App.TestController = Em.Controller.extend
    fullname: (->
        @get('name') + 123
    ).property('name')
```

It'll wrap your function with an extra set of parenthesis, but everything will still work as expected.

Comment: That really can solve my problem, thank you